# c++ passing pointer or not into function

Tags: c++, pointers

what is the difference when i do function call in c++ to object method with pointer and not
from this :

```
void Main::Init()
{
    Foo foo;
    Obj obj;
    Obj.someMethod(foo)  // signeture : someMethod(Foo f)
}
```

to this:

```
void Main::Init()
{
    Foo* foo = new foo();
    Obj obj;
    Obj.someMethod(foo)  // signeture : someMethod(Foo* f)
}
```

**UPDATE**
or this :

```
 void Main::Init()
    {
        Foo* foo  = new foo();
        Obj obj;
        Obj.someMethod(foo)  // signeture : someMethod(Foo *& f)
    }
```

what is better in term's of memory and compiler what is more recommended
in practical i don't see any differences in both i get what i need out of Foo

Comment: There is something wrong in the code: In the second example, I think you wanted `obj` to be the pointer, not `foo`.

Comment: Not just that, in each example, the signature is wrong. (I think you have `foo` and `obj` mixed up in the calls.)

Comment: fixed sorry updated the eample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
someMethod(Foo f)
```

`f` is **an object passed by instance**, i.e. `f` becomes a copy of the actual parameter `foo` passed into the function. Any modifications done to `f` by `someMethod` wouldn't change `foo`.

Typically, it would be more efficient to pass f by **a const reference**: `someMethod(const Foo& f)`. Thus, copying would be avoided and a call of a non-const method of `f` in `someMethod` would cause a compiler error.

```
someMethod(Foo *f)
```

`f` is **a pointer to an object**. Provided that the actual parameter `foo` is initialized (unlike your example), any modifications made by `someMethod` to *the object pointed by* `f` would actually apply to the object pointed by `foo`.

```
someMethod(Foo *& f)
```

`f` is **a reference to a pointer to an object**. This is usually used to declare an output parameter of a pointer type. Example:

```
void someMethod(Foo *& f)
{
  f = new Foo();
}
```

As `f` is a reference to the actual parameter `Foo* foo`, the result of `new Foo` is assigned to `foo` on the function exit.

Comment: fixed , also what is the recomened way to use , if i only want to get 
the info inside the f object , can i use just the first method?
in term's of memory ?

Comment: @user63898: neither, see the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Firstly that code doesn't compile.

In the second snippet, `foo` is a pointer, and `obj` is an object. You're invoking foo.someMethod(obj) when its expecting a `Foo*` object. Same with the first snippet as well.

From what I see you meant:

`obj.someMethod(foo);`

Explanation:

in the first snippet, `foo` is an object. The object is passed as a COPY to `someMethod` function.(call by value). Changes made to `foo` in `someMethod` will not reflect in the `foo` of `Main::Init()`.

In the second snippet, `foo` is sent as a pointer to object. Its called "call by reference". The address of `foo` will be sent to `someMethod` so that it can modify the object or do **something** with it